# Angular 2 Filter Pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-pipe

Trying to write a custom pipe to hide some items.

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';

// Tell Angular2 we're creating a Pipe with TypeScript decorators
@Pipe({
    name: 'showfilter'
})

export class ShowPipe {
    transform(value) {
        return value.filter(item => {
            return item.visible == true;
        });
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<flights *ngFor="let item of items | showfilter">
</flights>
```

COMPONENT

```
import { ShowPipe } from '../pipes/show.pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'results',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/results.html',
    pipes: [PaginatePipe, ShowPipe]
})
```

My item has the property of visible, which can be true or false.

However nothing showing, is there something wrong with my pipe?

I think my pipe is working because when I change the pipe code to:

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';

// Tell Angular2 we're creating a Pipe with TypeScript decorators
@Pipe({
    name: 'showfilter'
})

export class ShowPipe {
    transform(value) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

It will show all items.

Thanks

Comment: did you add `pipes: [ShowPipe]` to the component where you are using the pipe? I can't see anything wrong in your code.

Comment: what happens if you make it an impure pipe? `@Pipe({
    name: 'showfilter', pure : false
})`

Comment: [Works as intended](http://plnkr.co/edit/3zwggBNfPJoUJ9YLGgJg?p=preview)

Comment: Hey I just did a quick test with your code, nothing is wrong (except not following recommended practice :P). Could you check if any of your items is having "visible" === true?

Comment: What do you mean by "not following recommended practice"? Any concrete hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because you have an initial value of `[]` for `items`. When you then later add items to `items`, the pipe is not reexecuted.

Adding `pure: false` should fix it:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'showfilter',
    pure: false
})
export class ShowPipe {
    transform(value) {
        return value.filter(item => {
            return item.visible == true;
        });
    }
}
```

`pure: false` has a big performance impact. Such a pipe is called every time change detection runs, which is quite often.

A way to make a pure pipe being called is to actually change the input value.

If you do

```
this.items = this.items.slice(); // create a copy of the array
```

every time after `items` was modified (added/removed) makes Angular recognize the change and re-execute the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

- It is not recommended to use impure pipe. I will impact your performance.
- It will be called even source has not been changed.
- So the correct alternative to be is change the reference of your returning object.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'showfilter'
})

export class ShowPipe {
    transform(value) {
        value = value.filter(item => {
            return item.visible == true;
        });
     const anotherObject = Object.assign({}, value) // or else can do cloning.
     return anotherObject 
    }
}
```