# Angular2 ngFor - skip if no value

Tags: angular

I have this json object:

```js
data = {

  "name": "somename",
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "Item 1",
      "description": "Some description for item1"
    },
    {
      "title": "Item 2",
      ""
    },
    {
      "title": "Item 3",
      "description": "Some description for item3"
    }
  ]
}
```

What would be the recommended way, with rc2, to *ngFor and display only items that have a description?

Html Template:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of data.items" class="item">
        <div>{{item.title}}</div>
        <div>{{item.description}}</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you add an *ngIf to the template ? Something like *ngIf="item.description".

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I would like to skip, or as a secondary option to hide, the li block.

Comment: You can use a filter pipe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827925/angular-2-filter-pipe/37828164#37828164

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add a `*ngIf` on the repeating element and check with a falsy conditional on the `length` property like so:

```html
<ul>
    <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="data.items">
        <li class="item" *ngIf="item?.description?.length">
            <div>{{item.title}}</div>
            <div>{{item.description}}</div>
        </li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

You can't access the `item` variable from the `*ngFor` in the `*ngIf` on the same element, that's why you need to add a `template` tag encapsulating the `li`.

---

> Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BCHwijqzOjWgZ2Xp4mXQ?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: How do I get the index of the iterated item when using this syntax? Originally I used something like this: `<li *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index">...</li>`.

Comment: What about if I am using table and I use ngFor on row?

Comment: Nothing changes. :D

Comment: deprecated use ng-template instead, works fine. And no one should do regular *ngFor = "let ..." instead use as specified in the answer

Comment: To get index: `<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="data.items" let-item let-index="index">`

Answer (score 1):

> display only items that have a description?

**Short solution**

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of data.items">
    <li class="item" *ngIf="item.description">
        <div>{{item.title}}</div>
        <div>{{item.description}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

OR use **ng-container** instead of **template** to keep the code clearer.

```
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data.items">
        <li class="item" *ngIf="item.description">
            <div>{{item.title}}</div>
            <div>{{item.description}}</div>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Comment: ng-container is what I was looking for. You can use it to do the html logic without breaking the css selector logic