# Pipe pure: true and ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm using a pipe on a ngFor loop for groupBy.

```
<div *ngFor="let ratePlan of ratePlans | groupBy: 'fonctionnel'">
```

The cinematic of data retrieve is the following :

- Retrieve ratePlans[] from @Input
- Retrieve 'fonctionnel' key with ratePlans[i].Id

My issue is on the pipe that run once with empty key. So I need to launch the groupBy pipe when 'fonctionnel' key is set.
If I set pipe as pure: false, then the groupby is working but all the next stuff is broken (every update on ratePlans[] refresh the page).

So how to resolve this problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put a condition in your pipe that checks if fonctionnel is set ?

Comment: The issue is the pipe is launched only once. If it is in pure: true, then 'fonctionnel' is ever empty. I need to relaunch pipe transform when it is set.

Comment: If your pipe is only launched once, then it's useless, you'd rather make a transform function to get your groupBy. The interest of a pipe is to be launched at every model change, not only once  !

Comment: So why pure attribute (by default equals true) exists ?

Comment: I'm quoting from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285550/what-is-impure-pipe-in-angular2) : `A pure pipe is only called when Angular detects a change in the value or the parameters passed to a pipe. An impure pipe is called for every change detection cycle no matter whether the value or parameters changes.`

Comment: So I suppose as the pipe is binded on an Array, no change is never detected when I set the key ? So how to throw a change event on Array ?

Comment: Ok, I have resolved my issue on a different way.