# Angular material Autocomplete filter object with keyvalue pipe

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I have a little problem, I have this:

```
foo = {
   parent1:[{
              data: "John",
           },
           {
              data: "Adam",
           },
           {
              data: "Eva",
           }],
   parent2:[{
              data: "Ricky",
           }]
}
```

and my autocomplete:

```
<input type="text" matInput [formControl]="query" [matAutocomplete]="autoGroup"/>
<mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let parents of foo | keyvalue" [label]="parents.key">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let data of parents.value"  [value]="data.data">
      {{ data.data }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-optgroup>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

And I want to set it a filter - I just want to filter by "data", for ex. if i type "John" - it will only remain John with optgroup "parent1"
I've created demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syzdzg-ytejbp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend you use [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe because it's impure, it means it would be called and translate you object to a new array every change detection cycle. See [Pure and impure pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes) section of the docs and this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39285550/4858777).

In any case it's easier to transform the object into an array and filter it after. You can find the [filter autocomplete](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dqdpkgyrdlr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts) example in the [angular material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples). In your case it looks like:

```
...
@Component(...)
export class AutocompleteFilterExample {
  ...

  readonly filteredFoo$ = this.query.valueChanges.pipe(
    map((query = '') => {
      const lowerCaseQuery = query.toLocaleLowerCase().trim();
      return Object.entries(this.foo)
        .map(([parentId, items]) => ([
          parentId,
          items.filter(item => {
            const lowerCaseData = item.data.toLocaleLowerCase();
            return lowerCaseData.includes(lowerCaseQuery);
          })
        ]))
        .filter(([prentId, items]) => items.length);
    })
  );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" matInput [formControl]="query" [matAutocomplete]="autoGroup"/>
<mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let parents of filteredFoo$ | async" [label]="parents[0]">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let data of parents[1]"  [value]="data.data">
      {{ data.data }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-optgroup>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syzdzg-bt2eiw?file=src/app/autocomplete-filter-example.ts)